# Jquery: load and before

Tags: jquery, ajax

iam noob @ jquery, and i should load a div generated by php to a place, before a specified element. How can i do that?
for example:

```
<div id="something_big">
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="third"></div>
</div>
```

Following comes from outside, between first and third div:

```
<div id="second"></div>
```

edit: i should merge the "load" and "insertafter" commands somehow

ty

Comment: Have you tried anything, post the code here.

Comment: how do you want the final output to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move a container behind another container, I would use the [insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) function. *The first element is the element, that shall be moved. The second element is the element that shall be above.*

```
$(function(){
    $("#second").insertAfter("#first");
});
```

[See example @ jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hhMFL/)

You want to load something. E.g. if you load a container that is located in another file:

```
$(function(){

   var loadedDiv = $("#randomDiv").load('ajax/test.html #container');
   $(loadedDiv).insertAfter("#intro");

});
```

To see more examples about the load function, visit the [jQuery documentation for this function](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Comment: jQuery("section#content > article > header > div#intro").insertAfter(jQuery.load(myUrl));

Something like that is possible?

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing the `insertAfter()` inside the `.load` callback? Otherwise, `loadedDiv` might not contain the loaded content yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#second').insertAfter('#first');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code : http://jsfiddle.net/b8mzs/1/

You just need add a div, after specified element

```
jQuery( function() {
  jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery("#first").after('<div id="second">2</div>');
});
```

With this, I'm specifing that after the div with id "first", jQuery should add string (which is another div).

noConflict() function is just my habit of writing in jQuery, you can use $ sign as well instead of it (remove jQuery.noConflict(); then)

Answer (score 0):

For the record, something clean

```
$.get("your.php", function(data) {
    $(data.trim()).insertBefore('#third');
});
```